# cannot connect to Mac using RenciSSH

Tags: c#, macos, ssh

I am not able to connect remotely to a Mac System (OS X 10.10.5) using Renci.SshNet library in a .NET application. The code I am using allows me to connect to any other linux OS systems such as RHL, Ubuntu etc. I am able to connect to this Mac System thru putty. But when I try to connect from my .NET application it gives me the following error -

> No suitable authentication method found to complete authentication (publickey,keyboard-interactive). Source - Renci.SshNet

This is my code. Please help

```
public SshClient sshClient;
sshClient = new SshClient(ipAddress, port, username, password);
sshClient.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
sshClient.Connect();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on various contributions on stackoverflow figured that mac was asking for a keyboard authentication, whereas my method only had a password based authentication. So this updated code does both.... Thanks to all contributors ...

```
        public SshClient sshClient;
        KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod kauth = new KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod(username);
        PasswordAuthenticationMethod pauth = new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(username, password);

        kauth.AuthenticationPrompt += new EventHandler<Renci.SshNet.Common.AuthenticationPromptEventArgs>(HandleKeyEvent);

        ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(ipAddress, port, username, pauth, kauth);

        sshClient = new SshClient(connectionInfo);
        sshClient.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
        sshClient.Connect();
```

and this event handler code for the password prompt event

```
        void HandleKeyEvent(Object sender, Renci.SshNet.Common.AuthenticationPromptEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Renci.SshNet.Common.AuthenticationPrompt prompt in e.Prompts)
        {
            if (prompt.Request.IndexOf("Password:", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
            {
                prompt.Response = password;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked perfectly for me.  I've made one alteration - so that the handler can be passed the password:  `kauth.AuthenticationPrompt += (sender, e) => HandleKeyEvent(sender, e, password);`    and signature change: 
`private static void HandleKeyEvent(Object sender, Renci.SshNet.Common.AuthenticationPromptEventArgs e, string password)`

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me with few changes (there is no port parameter in new library version, and the server sends the word "Password:" without ":", like this "Password").

Comment: Thank you very much!! Worked for me like a charm!! Saved my day. It could be better if can be wrapped as a class.